# Mongodb - return an array of _id of all updated documents

Tags: mongodb

I need to update some documents in one collection, and send an array of the `_id`s of the updated documents to another collection.

Since `update()` returns the *number* of updated items *not their ids*, I've come up with the following to get the array:

```js
var docsUpdated = [];
var cursor = myCollection.find(<myQuery>);
cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
  myCollection.update({_id : doc._id}, <myUpdate>, function(error, response){
    docsUpdated.push(doc._id);
  });
});
```

Or I could do:

```js
var docsUpdated = myCollection.distinct("_id", <myQuery>);
myCollection.update(<myQuery>, <myUpdate>, {multi : true});
```

I'm guessing the second version would be faster because it only calls the database twice. But both seem annoyingly inefficient - is there another way of doing this without multiple database calls? Or am I overcomplicating things?

Comment: After I search some related post in here, it seems your second option could be better...

Comment: yeah my issue with the second one is: what if any of the updates failed (e.g. because it broke schema rules) - then the _id would be in the docsUpdated array, but that doc would not have been updated. (This only just occurred to me)

Comment: Wow, maybe the [bulk operation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) could be one option for you...

Comment: MongoDB does not support this natively. The relevant bug is https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-714. Please upvote it if it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the cursor operator ".aggregate()"

```
db.orders.aggregate([
                 { $group: { _id: "$_id"} }
               ])
```

something along those lines that returns the results of all the id's in the collection